# Add line to file with MaxScript

Tags: file-io, append, maxscript

I have a file:

```
A

Some text

Sum up
```

I can create that file easily with `MaxScript`'s `format "..." to:file`.

But **how to add some lines to already existing and not empty file**?

For the most, I would like to add the **line with `my text`**:

1. **After specified text occurence** (.e.g after `Some text`, in new line)
2. **At specified line** (e.g. in empty line #4 and add new line after it)

If it's not possible, then maybe **can I append something to file** (write it after `Sum up`)?

---

**p.s.**
I could always read the whole file to variable, add my text to it and then save the file.

But it's not really an option for big files (and I want to make it fast).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To append to a file, use the openFile with "a" as the mode argument. The full documentation can be found at [FileStream Values](http://docs.autodesk.com/3DSMAX/14/ENU/MAXScript%20Help%202012/files/GUID-BB041082-3EEF-4576-9D69-5B258A59065-493.htm):

```
fs = openFile "c:/Temp/YourFile.txt" mode:"a"
print "This line will be appended to your file" to:fs
close fs

-- Insert some text in the middle of a file
fsadd = openFile "c:/Temp/YourFile.txt" mode:"a+"
skipToString fsadd "Some text to write"
skipToNextLine fsadd
print "Insert New Text" to:fsadd
close fsadd
```

Comment: Thanks man! Docu, sample code and explanation. That's why I love that community :)

Comment: Be aware that the file must exist before writing to it. It will not create it like most languages.